# Is there a way for a ListView within Grid to inherit the grid's ColumnDefinitions & RowDefinitions?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm essentially trying to create a view that displays a list of items underneath an interactable header (a `Button` and an `Image` wrapped in a `FlexLayout`) that sorts that specific column A-Z / Z-A, my problem is that I can't figure out how to line them up neatly and without manually setting the column width in `ColumnDefinition`.

Normally I'd just set the width to some value but since its going to be cross platform (including tablets) I want to avoid doing that so I don't end up with everything squished to one side if the user decides to use a tablet with a much wider screen, does anyone know any fixes or have any advice on what I could look into trying?

Thanks in advance, and I'll post a snippet of what I'm ***trying*** to achieve below

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Button Text="Name" FontSize="8" Clicked="QuickSort" Padding="0"/>
        <Image Source="" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" IsVisible="False"/>
    </FlexLayout>

    <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Text="Type" FontSize="8" Clicked="QuickSort" Padding="0"/>
        <Image Source=""  Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" IsVisible="False"/>
    </FlexLayout>

    <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <Button Text="Cost" FontSize="8" Clicked="QuickSort" Padding="0"/>
        <Image Source=""  Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" IsVisible="False"/>
    </FlexLayout>

    <ListView ItemSource="{Binding Collection}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding type}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding cost}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to copy the Grid column declarations into the ItemTemplate's DataTemplate. This makes each item a Grid, whose columns match the outer Grid:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *">
                <Label Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding type}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding cost}" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The labels all default to "Row=0", so each item is a one-row Grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to make it easier, maybe try some datagrid libraries like https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid